# Htacess - restrict url apart from 3 IP addresses

Tags: .htaccess, ip-address, restriction, whitelist

My magento admin store has a custom url, let's say it is 'sunset' so the url to access the admin is either:

```
www.mystore.com/index.php/sunset

www.mystore.com/sunset
```

I now want to be able to restrict this access to only 3 IP addresses, if not it redirects back to the homepage.

I have my htaccess code like so which works for a single IP:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?sunset [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11.333.22.33
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

and works perfectly. However when I then try and include 2 other IP addresses like below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?sunset [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11.222.33.444 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11.222.55.444 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11.333.22.33
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

It allows access to anyone.

What am I missing?